# how can manage laravel 5 login page after the logging?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have created laravel 5 login and registration form using make:auth command. but I have both home.blade.php and front.blade.php in My layouts folder. My problem is this I need front.blade.php file when I visit to My web app as My index page(opening page of the site). and then I need home.blade.php file when I logging with the system. (to do cms works). I thing target place is routes.php

This is routes.php

```
Route::auth();






Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('front');
});


Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
});


Route::get('/about',function(){
    return view('about');
});

Route::get('/bod',function(){
    return view('bod');
});

Route::get('/st',function(){
    return view('st');
});

Route::get('/services',function(){
    return view('services');
});

Route::get('/contact',function(){
    return view('contact');
});

Route::get('/welcome',function(){
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

but when I use above routes My web app always redirect to front.blade.php file after the logging with the system. I need redirect with home.blade.php after the logging with the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check inside the front route and redirect to home if the user is logged in.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return redirect('home');
}
```

Comment: sucess with this scripts Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
             return view('home');
    }
    return view('front');
});